# Images won't show and/or won't work with buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have added one image at the moment but it's grey. Button won't work as intended too, but it may be a reason of broken image (because code seems to be right).

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to make switch button your approach is not good. You can use `Switch` or `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` or if that doesn't full fill your wishes you can customise it or use some third party library like for example: https://github.com/zcweng/SwitchButton
Which makes switch button in iOS style

Answer (score 0):

U can change drawable for button by `android:background="@android:drawable/..."` property. But I think u want to obtain `switch` or `ToogleButton` so it should be different View.

Answer (score 0):

1> You can use `Switch` for that.

2> Change your `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` if you want your layout to appear.

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it looks like - [image]

Comment: After changing it android studio just shows "android...LinearLayout" caption instead of objects. P.S If this code is kinda bad don't mind me, i'm still learning, mostly from tutorials. I will edit it later if it won't work as it should.

Comment: I am sure, you are missing something, I have edited my answer with appropriate layout. check it out.

Comment: Let me know if you want an switch like 2nd image? If so, you are not going right way.

Comment: Ok now it works but it's the same as with constraint layout. I want this button to change from 1st png to 2nd png when turned off and on, but i don't want to ask for too much, main problem is that they won't appear as they should.

Comment: I'm one step forward, because it shows my object, not rectangle, but android studio sees it as completely grey (as shown on my screens). It's png so it should work.